# Vertically scrollable in jQuery Mobile with search

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

How to do this:

A B C D ... is scrollable.

When page is launch, it displays all item.

When user clicks on an letter ie 'D', it would go to the first item occurrence that starts with the letter.

Example Image attached

[image]

Comment: Instead of a problem you are asking for a full fledged solution. Please provide your attempt at the solution and the problem you are facing there.

Comment: @sbjumani: I am not getting any idea how to perform this..

Comment: use animate scrollTop --  https://jsfiddle.net/r61y1g9g/